# JComboBox selection failed

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

if I try to select elements of a JComboBox by a different thread it leads to a very strange behaviour and selects nearly everytime the last element of the list. Is this a bug or a stupid mistake?

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test3 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test3 frame = new Test3();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Test3() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 200, 80);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    String[] select = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    final JComboBox<String> jb = new JComboBox<String>(select);
    contentPane.add(jb, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    new Thread() {
        int i = 0;

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                i++;
                if (i > 4)
                    i = 0;
                jb.setSelectedIndex(i);
                System.out.println("SELECT " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

    setContentPane(contentPane);
}}
```

This example shows a simple JComboBox with 5 elements given by a String-Array inside.
Every 3 seconds the defined thread selects the next item with the help of

```
jb.setSelectedIndex(i);
```

and the console prints the selection as well. Running that code shows the mentioned strange behaviour: The console counts every three seconds 0-4, the JComboBox selects most of the time the last one in the list..

Comment: Swing is not thread safe. You should not try selecting from a different thread then the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). Consult the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information

Comment: @Robin You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help,
the easiest fix I found is to let Swing handle this:

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test3 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test3 frame = new Test3();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Test3() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 200, 80);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    String[] select = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    final JComboBox<String> jb = new JComboBox<String>(select);
    contentPane.add(jb, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    new Thread() {
        int i = 0;

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                i++;
                if (i > 4)
                    i = 0;
                System.out.println("SELECT " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    try {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                jb.setSelectedIndex(i);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    setContentPane(contentPane);
   }
}
```

Comment: use invokeLater(). invokeAndWait() should be avoided!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the **JCombobox** update in the **event dispatch thread** using invokeLater():

```
public Test3() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 200, 80);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    String[] select = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    final JComboBox<String> jb = new JComboBox<String>(select);
    contentPane.add(jb, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    new Thread() {
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                i++;
                if (i > 4)
                    i = 0;

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        jb.setSelectedIndex(i);

                    }
                });

                System.out.println("SELECT " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

    setContentPane(contentPane);
}}
```